# Setup Issue on New Installation Magento 2.3.3 in ubuntyu

Tags: magento2

nvironment
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
PHP 7.3.13
mysql Ver 8.0.19

I installed all the source file for Magento 2.3.3 using composer command.
Composer command ended with no issue
Configured apache2 host server and PHP
Configured mysql and created a new database DbMagento
Accessed through Browser to Magento Setup
Filled all the information requested and reached the last step:
1 - Readiness Check = no issue
2 - Add a Database = no issue
3 - Web Configuration = no issue
4 - Customize your store = no issue
5 - Create Admin Account = no issue
6 - install = ISSUE

During the last step "6" relating to install ... system performs initial installation and then stops ... see console Log herewith

`Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_AdminAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Amqp':

Module 'Magento_AmqpStore':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_AuthorizenetGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_BraintreeGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':
[ERROR] Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Unable to apply patch Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\EnableSegmentation for module Magento_Catalog. Original exception message: Invalid column data type "" in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchApplier.php:241
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1004): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applySchemaPatch('Magento_Catalog')
#1 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(832): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array)
#3 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#5 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#6 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(116): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#10 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /var/www/magento/setup/index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#14 {main}`

Answer (score 0):

you can add the code in file
vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
line 1846
after line
case 'smallint':
add
case 'smallint unsigned':
and
after line
case 'int':
add
"case 'int unsigned':"

or full method code

```
protected function _getColumnTypeByDdl($column)
{
    switch ($column['DATA_TYPE']) {
        case 'bool':
            return Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN;
        case 'tinytext':
        case 'char':
        case 'varchar':
        case 'text':
        case 'mediumtext':
        case 'longtext':
            return Table::TYPE_TEXT;
        case 'blob':
        case 'mediumblob':
        case 'longblob':
            return Table::TYPE_BLOB;
        case 'tinyint':
        case 'smallint':
        case 'smallint unsigned':
            return Table::TYPE_SMALLINT;
        case 'mediumint':
        case 'int':
        case 'int unsigned':
            return Table::TYPE_INTEGER;
        case 'bigint':
            return Table::TYPE_BIGINT;
        case 'datetime':
            return Table::TYPE_DATETIME;
        case 'timestamp':
            return Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP;
        case 'date':
            return Table::TYPE_DATE;
        case 'float':
            return Table::TYPE_FLOAT;
        case 'decimal':
        case 'numeric':
            return Table::TYPE_DECIMAL;
    }
}
```